# Azure Event Grid to Azure Relay, Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-hybrid-connections

I'm testing out Azure Event Grid with a Azure Relay, Hybrid Connection handler. It's not working for me.

I can see messages being published to Azure Event Grid. So far so good.

I've set up a subscription to the Event Grid topic and I've configured it to send events to a handler specified as an Azure Relay with a Hybrid Connection endpoint.

Looking at the metrics for the subscription with the Hybrid Connection handler, I see the following telemetri:

- Matched Events
- Delivery Failed
- Expired Events

… but I see no Delivery Succeeded event???

Also, the Hybrid Connection listener (just a simple Console App) connected to the Azure Relay receives nothing. I've tested the listener by sending some test messages directly to the Relay and that works fine.

The logical conclusion, is that the events published to the Event Grid are not being delivered probably to the Relay Hybrid Connection handler. But why? There are not that many parameters, so I not sure what I'm doing wrong. It seems rather straight forward to configure this.

I'm a the point where I'm beginning to believe that the Event Grid / Hybrid Connection scenario is currently not working. It is in [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/event-grid/custom-event-to-hybrid-connection) after all, so that could explain it.

I know that there is not much to go on here, but I was hoping that others might have some experience with this?

The issue still remains. The issues seems to be related to the formating of the json being passed from the Event Grid Subscription to the Hybrid Connect.

**Update**

I finally had some time to look more carefully into this.

I set up the [Event Grid Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester) and every time the Event Grid recieves a message I can see this error in the log:

`HybridConnection: Message processing failed - Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.`

I'm still not able to fix this, as I do not control the message. The message is generated by Azure Logic App and send to the Event Grid using the Event Grid connector. The Event Grid Connector in Azure Logic Apps is in preview, so that might explain the challenges I'm seeing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Subscription with Hybrid Connection endpoint is working very well. I do recommend to look at this simple-http server/client implementation for test purposes, https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay/tree/master/samples/hybrid-connections/dotnet/simple-http

Comment: I think maybe the issue is introduced by Logic App, producing some json that causes challenges further down the chain. See update.

Comment: see my answer, where using a http POST to the hybrid connection url can help you with the hybridconnection subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully tested Event Grid subscriber locally using Azure Relay and documented it [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-eventgrid-testing-with-azure-relay). It is based on a sample Microsoft is providing and implemented using WCF variant of client, not the [.NET Standard version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay-dotnet).

Comment: Thank you. That is good to know. WCF is not supported in the Azure Portal GUI (I've added the screen shoot in the question above), only Hybrid Connection can be chosen. I suppose WCF can be configured using the Azure CLI. I'm using the .NET Standard variant - that seems to be where the future is heading.

Answer (score 1):

you can simulate an Event Grid message to the HybridConnection url using a http POST request:

```
POST https://{myNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{myHybridConnectionName}

headers:
    content-type: application/json
    x-ms-version: 2015-07-08
    Aeg-Event-Type: Notification
    Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=xxx&sig=xxxx&se=11111111&skn=xxxxx

body:
    {
       "id": "123456",
       "eventTime": "2018-07-22T13:09:07.5164877Z",
       "eventType": "recordInserted",
       "dataVersion": "1.0",
       "metadataVersion": "1",
       "subject": "/myapp/vehicles/motorcycles",
       "data": {
          "make": "Ducati",
          "model": "Monster"
       }
   }
```

Note, that the sasToken for authorization header can be copied from the *Azure Event Grid Tester* log panel, when the HybridConnection has been opened.

the other option is to generate it by the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Relay;
// ... 
var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("hybridconnectionPolicyName", "hybridconnectionPrimaryKey");
var token = tokenProvider.GetTokenAsync("https://{myNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{myHybridConnectionName}", TimeSpan.FromDays(10)).Result.TokenString;
```

Comment: I created an Azure Function. So instead of making a subscription between the Event Grid Topic and the Hybrid Connection, I subscribe to an Azure Function that then sends the event on to the Hybrid Connection. Essentially creating an intermediate step in the sequence. This works. However, it's a workaround and I still think that the initial approach of making a subscription that connects the Event Grid Topic to the Hybrid Connection would be a simpler and cleaner solution.

Comment: You can use an EventGridTester for full end-to-end eventing test scenario from the FireTopic and receiving an event on the HybridConnection opened by tester. Go to the custom topic resource, then create a new subscription with a HybridConnection endpoint (opened by tester). The FireTopic node allows to publish an event to the Event Grid. You should see all event messages for this subscription in the Events node.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any ideas related to the error I'm seeing when using the EventGridTester: ´'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'´?

Comment: The payload of an event message must be either JArray or JObject (it is depended from the eventDeliverySchema). This error shows a JValue such as a text, primitive type, etc. Use the http POST request from my answer to play with a payload or attach a debugger and setup the breakpoint at the line = 1797 of the source file = Form1.cs

Comment: My challenge here is that the payload comes from Logic App. I can only control the formatting by intercepting the event, which is what I now do with an Azure Function. I consider inserting an Azure Function a work-around.

Comment: If your Logic App is a source of interest (publisher) for custom topic, the payload must be in the recognized input schema such as: EventGridSchema, CloudEventSchema or CustomEventSchema (this last one is still in preview). Note, that the CustomEventSchema requires to populate an additional property such as inputSchemaMapping, where each mandatory properties such as id, topic, eventType, eventTime, subject and dataVersion must have a mapping for sourceField and defaultValue. The CustomEventSchema is fine for not complicate mapping values from your payload to the custom topic payload.

Comment: In the second case, when your Logic App is a subscriber to the Event Grid custom topic, then you should use a http POST request to the HybridConnection url, like is shown in my answer.

Comment: Logic App is a Microsoft Azure Service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/. I don't control what json that Logic App's produces. My current conclusion is that there's a bug in Logic App -> Event Grid connection. It is in preview after all. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukhybridcloud/2018/08/10/building-an-azure-event-grid-app-part-2-adding-a-logic-app-subscriber-to-the-event-grid-topic/. And yes in my case, the source of the event comes from Logic App. Logic App is not subscribing to an event, but is triggered from elsewhere (an Alexa skill actually)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179822/discussion-between-jasper-h-bojsen-and-roman-kiss).